# Rails Admin - Model Association has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

So I have rails_admin installed in my application and I am building some sort of a grading system for practice. For now, there are Courses, Classes and Students models setup.

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :my_classes
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :my_classes 
end

class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :course
    has_and_belongs_to_many :students
end
```

Using has_and_belongs_to_many between Classes and Students in rails_admin gives me a widget to include as many students in a class as I want and enroll students in as many classes as I want. However, Course can also have more than one Classes and logically, a Student should only be able to enroll in one class per course.

How do I ensure in rails_admin that a Student can only enroll in 1 Class per Course?